# Why is my greater than SQL query not working?

Tags: sql-server

On the query below I am wanting to left outer join onto table3. Shouldn't this result in all of the rows that have an ID greater than the table ID in table1.

This to me should return all of the rows in table3 that are greater than table1 ID. How is this not the case then.

**Question: Is this supposed to return all of the rows that have an ID that 
            is greater than table1 ID?**

Note: I know that switching the order of the tables around in the **from** clause 
      will change the resulting dataset.

```
select t1.ID, t1.Value, 
       t3.ID, t3.Value 
from table1 as t1
       left outer join 
     table3 as t3 on t1.ID > t3.ID;
```

**Result:**

```
  1 First   NULL NULL
  2 Second     1 First
```

**Table1:**

```
 ID Value
  1 First
  2 Second
```

**Table3:**

```
 ID Value
  1 First
  2 Second
  3 Third
  4 Fourth
  5 Fifth
  6 Sixth
  7 Seventh
  8 Eighth
```

---

This query returns the result table that I think that it should for this type of query. But the first example does not work like I think that it should. Because this matches all of the right tabel with an ID which is less than the current t1.ID which is how it should work. (look above)

```
select t1.ID, t1.Value, 
       t3.ID, t3.Value 
from table1 as t1
       left outer join 
     table3 as t3 on t1.ID < t3.ID;
```

**Result:**

```
  1 First   2   Second
  1 First   3   Third
  1 First   4   Fourth
  1 First   5   Fifth
  1 First   6   Sixth
  1 First   7   Seventh
  1 First   8   Eighth
  2 Second  3   Third
  2 Second  4   Fourth
  2 Second  5   Fifth
  2 Second  6   Sixth
  2 Second  7   Seventh
  2 Second  8   Eighth
```

Comment: So **what** do you think is wrong with the first result set?

Comment: `x > y` means that `x` is greater than `y`. Look again at what you have on either side of `>`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you get a result for each combination of rows in t1 and t3 where the t1 id is greater, but if NO rows would be generated for a row in t1, you get the row from t1, and all NULLs for the t3 row.

So the "1, First" row in t1 is not greater than any rows in t3, and you get this in the output as a result:

1, First, NULL, NULL

For the "2, Second" row in t1, it's id is greater than the "1, First" row in t3, so you get this in the output as a result:

2, Second, 1, First

This is all as expected.

Your second query also works as expected - for the data set you have, the result is exactly the same as if you'd used INNER JOIN rather than LEFT JOIN, as you don't have any rows in t1 which do not have at least one match for your join predicate in t3.